# DbContext disposed when iterating through list fetched by awaiting ToListAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

Given the following code in my EF repository:

```
IRepository
{
    Task<IEnumerable<MyEntity>> GetEntities(Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>, IQueryable<);
}

EFRepository : IRepository
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntity>> GetEntities(Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>, IQueryable<MyEntity>> projection)
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var query = context.MyEntities
                .Include(e => e.RelatedEntity);
            return await projection(query).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

and something like this in the service layer where I consume the repo (the service layer has some validation and filtering in the real-world case)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyEntity>> GetEntities()
{
    // _repo is constructor injected
    // In this example, we just add a simple filter, but in the actual
    // code the query is built based on several input parameters
    return await _repo.GetEntities(query => query.Where(entity => entity.SomeProperty == "SomeValue"));
}
```

I'm getting an `ObjectContextDisposed` when I'm iterating through the `IEnumerable<MyEntity>` after awaiting the task from the service layer.

I was under the impression that the call to `.ToListAsync()` would actually make sure that the collection was fetched from the database and ready to use when returning, much like `ToList` does synchronously.

I've also tried adding `.AsNoTracking()` to the query, but I get the same error.

Are my assumptions about `.ToListAsync()` incorrect?

Comment: Best guess: you have lazily-loaded properties or relations. You should either eagerly load them or keep the context open for as long as you need to lazily load them

Comment: *Does* your entity class have relations?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, it does. I should have included that in my sample case. I do `.Include()` them, but I'll investigate and see if there's something in the mapping that's causing them to load lazily anyway and get back.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: As you guessed, I was missing some `.Include()` statements. Adding them solved the problem! :) If you'd like to write this up as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.